# Возможно ли запросом в MySQL выбрать таблицу?

Tags: mysql, sql

Возможно ли написать SQL-запрос типа "Select table From `DBname` Where `date` > '2017-02-11'"?
Если да, то как правильно это сормулировать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html

Comment: спасибо. частично помогло это
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_schema = 'your_database_name';

но как мне теперь запрос допилить, чтоб оно только ту таблицу выдало, где date > '2017-02-11'?

Comment: Вторую ссылку гляньте, что по вашему значит дата? создание? изменение? собственно по второй ссылке описание содержимого таблицы `information_schema.tables`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE datacolumn BETWEEN "2008.11.01"  AND  "2009.10.12"
```

Как пример. Если формат поля точно date.